Global sections of $L^n$ vs $L^{-n}\otimes \Omega_X^1$
In "UN THÉORÈME D'ANNULATION EN CARACTERISTIQUE POSITIVE" by Renée LEWIN-MÉNÉGAUX, there is the following paragraph after Proposition 2: (roughly translated into English)
[...] So $h^0(X, L^n)$ tends to infinity with $n$, and therefore there exists $n_0 \geq 0$ such that for all $n\geq n_0$, $h^0(X, L^n)$ is non-zero, and $n_1 \geq 0$ such that for all $n\geq n_1$, $h^0(X, L^{-n}\otimes \Omega_X^1)$ is zero.
Here, $X$ is a smooth projective surface over $k$, which is algebraically closed of positive characteristic, and $L$ is a nef and big line bundle.
My question is aimed at the second claim. Why does this imply that $h^0(X, L^{-n}\otimes \Omega_X^1)=0$ for large enough $n$?
EDIT: for reference, page 45 of this document: http://www.numdam.org/item/AST_1981__86__R1_0.pdf

Assume $H^0(X, L^{-n} \otimes \Omega^1_X) \ne 0$ for some $n$. Then there is a morphism $L^n \to \Omega^1_X$, and it must be an embedding of sheaves. Therefore, we have an embedding
$$
H^0(X,L^n) \subset H^0(X,\Omega^1_X),
$$
hence $h^0(X,L^n) \le h^0(X,\Omega^1_X)$. Since the right side is constant while the left side tends to infinity, it follows that $n$ is bounded.

Can you elaborate why it must be an embedding of sheaves?

If the kernel has rank 0, it is torsion, but $L^n$ is torsion free. If the kernel has rank 1, then the image has rank 0, hence it is torsion, but $\Omega^1_X$ is torsion free. Thus, the kernel must be zero.

Thanks, that makes sense.
